# How to Save Multi datagridview value generated on runtime using VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I Create panel
inside of it label , datagridview on run time base in database

example: i got 3 group of panel at runtime
Problem: When i click the save button the last group of panel only save into database

How do i save datagrid value to my database base in all generated datagridview at run time

This is my code in saving the value into database:

```
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
  a.getAllCandidateValue(lbl.Text) 
  i = a.id 
  For r As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1 
    If ii = dgv.RowCount - 1 Then 
      Exit For 
    Else 
      For cy As Integer = 0 To dgv.ColumnCount - 1 
         Dim scorePercentage As Double 
         strng = dgv.Columns(cy).HeaderText 
         Dim cellValue As String = dgv.Rows(r).Cells(cy).Value
    cr.getcriteriaIdByString(strng) scorePercentage = cellValue * cr.cri_per 
cScore.saveScoreCandidate(cr.id, scorePercentage, i, c.CATEGORY_ID, GLOBAL_VARS.currentid) 
Next 
cScore.getScore(i, c.CATEGORY_ID, GLOBAL_VARS.currentid) 
Dim total As Double = cScore.total cScore.saveScoreBYcategory(i, c.CATEGORY_ID, total, GLOBAL_VARS.currentid) 
End If 
ii = ii + 1 
Next 
Next
```